# Java scripts disable button on looping table

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I want to disable button on my table depend on if else statement. That table have some data while loop form mysql query. The problem is, the code that i currently use only disable the first button only. How do i want to disable another button if they don't meet the requirement statement. 
Here my table code and disable button code. Your kindness helped me very much appreciated.
[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaZdt.png)

```js
 <?php
      $query_p_peribadi = sprintf("SELECT * FROM pergerakan_peribadi WHERE no_ic = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_p_peribadi, "text"));
$p_peribadi = mysql_query($query_p_peribadi, $pspm) or die(mysql_error());
//$totalRows_p_rasmi = mysql_num_rows($p_rasmi);
    while($row_p_peribadi = mysql_fetch_assoc($p_peribadi)){
      $i=$row_p_peribadi['nopermohonan'];
    ?>
    
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row_p_peribadi['perkara']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_p_peribadi['tempat']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_p_peribadi['tarikh_keluar']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_p_peribadi['tarikh_masuk']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row_p_peribadi['status']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_p_peribadi['pegawai_pengesah']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row_p_peribadi['level_pegawai']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2<?php echo $row_p_peribadi['nopermohonan']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> Butiran</a>
           <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-info" onclick="myFunction()" id="kemaskini1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3<?php echo $row_p_peribadi['nopermohonan']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Kemaskini</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $row_p_peribadi['nopermohonan']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Batal</a>
```

```js
        <script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
 if (textstatus1.value == "Dalam Proses Kelulusan") {
alert("Permohonan Ini Masih Belum Di Luluskan Oleh Pegawai Pelulus");
document.getElementById("<?php echo $i;?>" ).disabled=true;
}else{

}
}
        </script>
```

```js
 <button  id="<?php echo $i;?>" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Kemaskini Pegerakan Bagi No Permohonan: <?php echo $row_p_peribadi['nopermohonan']; ?>?')" class="btn btn-success">Kemaskini</button>
```

Comment: Where is your jQuery? I only see ordinary Javascript.

Comment: should i use jQuery? sorry sir still new ..

Comment: Do whatevery you want. I'm just wondering why you tagged this with `jquery` if you're not using it.

Answer (score 1):

You can have only one `id` in your entire page.

```
document.getElementById("Kemaskini").disabled = true;

<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-info" id="Kemaskini" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3<?php echo $row_p_peribadi['nopermohonan']; ?>">
                                           ^         ^
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Kemaskini
</a>
```

`Kemaskini` this id is present more than once. So only `disable` is working for first element.

Try using class with some database id

Comment: you have made your id as Kemaskini.$i??

Comment: my id button i take from database. $i=$row_p_peribadi['nopermohonan'];

Comment: now is the id's on your page dufferent from each other??

Comment: i think yes. that why i can disable only one button. because that button loop from database.

Comment: im upload picture. have take look.

Comment: also check this line `document.getElementById("'.$i.'" ).disabled=true;`

Comment: i want to use id like this:id="myModal3<?php echo $row_p_peribadi['nopermohonan']; ?>"